# Installing Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 instead of the default Apache 2.4

Tags: package-management

I want to install Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04. But I can’t find this version package in apt-cache policy apache2. How install it? Where to find it? Can this be done?

Comment: 14.04 is EoL, its software repositories are no longer available. Please upgrade to a supported release. 16.04 or 18.04 are the currently supported LTSs.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Ok I have 16.04. Can I install apache version 2.2.22?

Comment: Likely not: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apache2

Comment: definitelly not. I believe, must be some way to install old packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If the main reason you want to downgrade Apache to version 2.2 instead of using 2.3, 2.4 or higher is configuration compatibility, just install and enable `mod_access_compat` to ensure your old configs work as expected.

Do you want to install Apache 2.2 because some of the syntax for configs have changed beginning with Apache 2.3? I was scared of doing this myself at one point, but honestly it’s fairly straightforward how to change configs from old to new [as explained here on the official Apache site](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html).

But if you simply don’t have the time — or you are not really comfortable doing that — then look into using the `mod_access_compat` module. As explained on [that page I linked to above](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html):

> **Mixing old and new directives**
>
> Mixing old directives like [`Order`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order), [`Allow`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#allow) or [`Deny`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#deny) with new ones like [`Require`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) is technically possible but discouraged. [`mod_access_compat`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html) was created to support configurations containing only old directives to facilitate the 2.4 upgrade. Please check the examples below to get a better idea about issues that might arise.

I would recommend installing Apache 2.4 but enable `mod_access_compat` and then — if and when time is available — go through the Apache configs you have and “modernize” them to use Apache 2.4 compatible config options.